# Apple Push Notification-Unable to callback didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have been simply trying to get deviceToken from my iPhone application using Apple Push Notification Service.
I don't have any implementation on server side for the time being.
I have created APP Id, got SSL certificate, Provision Profile with APN and calling

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
//view init and add sub view to window
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
}
```

method. 
When I execute the application it pop ups action box to allow Push Notification (means my request for APN registration is working) but my callback is not executed. Neither **didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken** nor **didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError** is called? can anybody help me to resolve the issue? Following are my callbacs for reference.

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {

            UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"APNClient" message:@"Entered into Error Method" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [myAlert show];
            [myAlert release];
            NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", err);

        }
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {
    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"APNClient" message:@"Got the deviceToken..!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [myAlert show];
    [myAlert release];        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The app should be using:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

not

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: zaph,
Thanks for your answer. But Apple document clearly says that - applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions will be used when you are working with message reception. I am yet trying to get deviceToken first.

Comment: The Apple dpcumentations states: It is recommended that you implement this method instead of applicationDidFinishLaunching:.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that PUSH notifications require port 5223 open in your network (if you are using WIFI), or otherwise, a cellular data connection.

I encountered the same problem in my home network, and had to open the port manually in the wireless router.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same and literally spent hours trying to get to the bottom of this. Ultimately, I figured my iPod touch simply was unable to connect to Apple to get the device token, but it had nothing to do with any firewall. Instead, the problem seemed to be into setting up some kind of (TLS?) encrypted connection in combination with **the device's clock that was reset to somewhere 1970**.

Updating the time fixed everything. Hope this helps someone out there :).

Answer (score -1):

The callbacks seem fine, as you say you should get a callback shortly after making the registration call (from anywhere).

This seems like a dumb question, but just to be sure - you delegate methods are in the application delegate class?

If so, I just can't see why your methods would not be called.  I see the NSLog statements there, but have you tried actually setting a breakpoint on entry?  And you are testing on the device, not the simulator, right?